# Bundle products doesn't appear in magento 2

Tags: magento2

i have create one product with Bundle Product 
if i use the theme Bundle Product is not showing in the page and i am getting below error
main.CRITICAL: Notice: Object of class Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\design\frontend\Megnor\mag110246_5\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml on line 83 [] []
if i use the default theme at that time i am getting the Product[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RHAi.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAwOa.jpg)

Comment: Seems like a bug in the theme you are using. Did you buy it from somewhere or did you create it yourself? In the latter case: Look at the datatype of the result you get from Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base. Maybe casting it as an int already fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace below code in list.phtml
File Path:-C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\design\frontend\Megnor\mag110246_5\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml
line 75-101 and 212-238
https://prnt.sc/qmvgmx
https://prnt.sc/qmvgs9

```html
<?php
                        if ($_product->getTypeId() != \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                            $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
                            $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
                            $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate(); 
                            $today = time();
                            if ($specialprice) {
                                if ($today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)) {
                                    $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
                                    $price = $_product->getPrice();
                                    $finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
                                    if($price >= $finalPrice){
                                        $sale = round( ($price - $specialprice) * 100 / $price);
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                        <span class="sale-label">
                                            <?php if($sale) { echo '-'.$sale.'%'; } else {echo __('Sale');} ?>
                                        </span>
                                <?php }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
```